# Automatic dimming light of screen on Asus laotop

Tags: brightness

So, I noticed from time to time, that brightness on my laptop goes down on it's own, although I have disabled auto-brightness (Control panel -> Display -> Night life -> OFF) and have it constantly at 100% (i take care of my eyes, lol).

What is possible to be "wrong" here or is there a possibility to raise brightnes over 100% at that time somehow? (with some sort of a trick or so?

Answer (score 1):

Night Life is not auto-brightness.

What you're facing is located in the Power Management options.

Power Management will change the brightness if the laptop is not charging.

Some laptops have software installed that will disconnect the charger cable programatically such that the laptop does not receive charge even though it is plugged in. As a result, the laptop works on battery, and Power Management will behave like this too.

You can change this behavior in the Power Management settings.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem. I'm constantly using it on power supply with removed battery (I always take out battery when I'm plugged into socket).

Comment: So... you obviously went to Power Management to make sure right?

Comment: yes, I have. Tried everysthing